# Windows Phone 7 Listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a list box in Windows Phone 7 and I want to display the list of Isolated Storage files in the list box and when I select the file from the list box I should be able to get the contents from the file.

Here is my code for that:

```
ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem;
string t = (string)lbi.Content;

using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using (var sr = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile(t, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
{
    textBlock2.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

And for binding files to the list:

```
var appstorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
string[] filename = appstorage.GetFileNames();
listBox1.ItemsSource = filename;
```

But when I try the application, on `SelectionChanged` event I get an error:

> *Invalid cast exception on `ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem;`*

Now the ultimate problem is that how do I retreive the exact file name in the list box when the `SelectionChanged` event is fired off, so that the file name can be used by the stream reader?

Answer (score 0):

You're binding to an `IEnumerable<string>` (`string[]`), the listbox does not convert those items in to `ListBoxItem`'s they're just regular old run of the mill strings.

So you should do:

```
string t = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;

using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using (var sr = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile(t, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
{
    textBlock2.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: That Solved My Problem,Hats Off.

Thank You!!